# Rails Not processing POST method after OPTIONS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

I have a Rails-API, where I have CORS setup with `rack-cors` gem. The API has a post model where I want to be able to make posts, like a basic scaffold thing. It's hosted on Heroku.

When I make a post request with `Axios` from my react frontend, it sends the OPTIONS preflight, but after that, the POST requests never made.

However, if I send the request with empty parameters, the request process fully after options and the post is made(though empty, I don't have any validations in place on the model).

My cors configuration:

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

My axios request from my React frontend.

```js
return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: authHeader.getApiUrl() + '/api/v1/posts',
      params: data,
      headers: authHeader.getHeader()
    })
```

```
at=info method=OPTIONS 
path="/api/v1/posts?cover_image="image 
url"&title=TItle&subtitle=The+Start+of+Something+New&tag=Tag&body=&specification=blog" 
host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=cddc8ded-849a-44c5-b655-1af87d29a71d fwd="102.67.23.174" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=287 protocol=https
```

Comment: Do you have strong parameters set up in the controllers? what does your log look like when then post is not called?

Comment: I have strong params setup up the controller, and sometimes it works, I just haven't been able to reproduce the working scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw someone bookmarked this, so I'll leave the answer for later references.

So the issue wasn't from Rails, it was from my Form submission handling in React. The request moved on to completion when I added `e.preventDefault()`, which I omitted the first time.

```js
createPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({loading: true})

    AdminServices.uploadPost(
      this.state.coverImageLink,
      this.state.title,
      this.state.subtitle,
      this.state.tag,
      this.state.body,
      this.state.specification
    ).then(resp => {
      this.switchTab("blog")
    }).catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response)
        this.setState({
          message: error.response.data.error,
          loading: false
        })
      } else if (error.request) {
        this.setState({
          message: "Please check your network",
          loading: false
        })
      } else {
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
  }
```